# Find chat_id in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I tried to create a bot in telegram with python, bot I can't find `chat_id`.
What should I do?

My code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup

updater = Updater(Token)
def start(update, _) :
    update.message.reply_text('Hello {}'.format(update.message.chat.first_name))

def service_keyboards(bot,update) :
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    keyboard = [['Send Video'], ['Send Music']]
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Plese choose an item.', reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

start_command = CommandHandler('start' , start)
service_command = CommandHandler('service' , service_keyboards)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(service_command)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Eror:

> No error handlers are registered, logging exception. Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\Ghazal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py",
> line 442, in process_update
> handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)   File "c:\users\Ghazal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py",
> line 160, in handle_update
> return self.callback(update, context)   File "", line 9, in start
> chat_id = update.message.chat_id AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'

Answer (score 1):

Command handler functions (in your case `start` function) accepts two arguments, first is `Update`, the second is `CallbackContext`.

You have misplaced your update argument in the function. It should come first:

```
def echo(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(str(update.message.chat_id) + ": " + 
update.message.text)
```

Your error message is clearly indicating that you are trying to access CollbackContex's message attribute. And CallbackContext does not have that.

Please refer to [these](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples) examples to learn more about telegram-bot library in python.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to `chat_id` for another methods. I edited my code now. please read my code again. I run cod and get these Eror again.

Comment: It does not matter. You just change your functions argument order from ```service_keyboards(bot,update)``` to ```service_keyboards(update, bot)```